# Recent modification to Twitter API?

Tags: c#, api, twitter, tweetsharp

I wrote a very simple C# application to send Tweets between to Windows machines.  To do this, each endpoint (ie this C#.NET desktop app that uses the TweetSharp library) has a timer, and when the Elapsed event fires all messages are gathered together with a GetDirectMessages() call, then these messages are parsed and processed by the endpoint.

My problem is that I built this over the course of a few hours two weeks ago and everything worked fine.  I dusted it off and executed a week ago as well, no problems.  Now, I break it out today and I am getting a very odd exception (see section EXCEPTION) that originate at the line "IEnumerable directMessage = service.ListDirectMessagesReceived();" (see section SOURCE).  My question is, since my code hasn't changed, is it possible that the API has (I know I know terribly unlikely).  Do any of the upstanding and erudite members of StackO have any thoughts?

Btw, I have checked and my ConsumerKey/Secret are valid, as is the cached OAuth access token that my authentication section uses.  It's odd because I can pull my list of followers, check my rate limiting stats, etc.  Also my NewtonSoft, Hammoch and TweetSharp references have not been updated/changed.

Thanks.

[SOURCE]

```
    private struct message
    {
        public long id;
        public string text;

        public message(long i, string t)
        {
            id = i;
            text = t;
        }
    }    

    private MessageEngine
    {
        /* Do auth -- excised for obvious reasons */

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 15000;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Start();
    }    

    private List<message> GetDirectMessages()
    {
        try
        {
            //Declarations:
            message message = new message();
            List<message> messages = new List<message>();
/*line 344*/IEnumerable<TwitterDirectMessage> directMessages = service.ListDirectMessagesReceived();

            //Fetch all current direct message:
            foreach (TwitterDirectMessage directMessage in directMessages)
            {
                //Store each message into a list, in reverse older:
                message = new message(directMessage.Id, directMessage.Text);
                messages.Insert(0, message);
            }

            return messages;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            List<message> messages = GetDirectMessages();
            LocalExecute(messages);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private bool LocalExecute(List<message> messages)
    {
        /* process messages */
    }
```

[EXCEPTION]

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize JSON array into type 'TweetSharp.TwitterDirectMessage'.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureArrayContract(Type objectType, JsonContract contract) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 412
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String reference) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 432
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 222
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueNonProperty(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 205
   at TweetSharp.Serialization.SerializerBase.DeserializeJson(String content, Type type) in C:\Users\Dimebrain\Desktop\Src\tweetsharp\src\vs2010\TweetSharp.Next\Serialization\SerializerBase.cs:line 60
   at TweetSharp.Serialization.JsonSerializer.AddDeserializedItem(String c, Type type, IList collection) in C:\Users\Dimebrain\Desktop\Src\tweetsharp\src\vs2010\TweetSharp.Next\Serialization\JsonSerializer.cs:line 131
   at TweetSharp.Serialization.JsonSerializer.DeserializeCollection[T](String content) in C:\Users\Dimebrain\Desktop\Src\tweetsharp\src\vs2010\TweetSharp.Next\Serialization\JsonSerializer.cs:line 90
   at TweetSharp.Serialization.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](String content) in C:\Users\Dimebrain\Desktop\Src\tweetsharp\src\vs2010\TweetSharp.Next\Serialization\JsonSerializer.cs:line 17
   at Hammock.RestClient.DeserializeEntityBody[T](RestBase request, RestResponse`1 response) in C:\Users\Dimebrain\Desktop\Src\hammock\src\net35\Hammock\RestClient.cs:line 2285
   at Hammock.RestClient.BuildResponseFromResult[T](RestBase request, WebQuery query) in C:\Users\Dimebrain\Desktop\Src\hammock\src\net35\Hammock\RestClient.cs:line 2212
   at Hammock.RestClient.Request[T](RestRequest request) in C:\Users\Dimebrain\Desktop\Src\hammock\src\net35\Hammock\RestClient.cs:line 107
   at TweetSharp.TwitterService.WithHammockImpl[T](RestRequest request) in C:\Users\Dimebrain\Desktop\Src\tweetsharp\src\vs2010\TweetSharp.Next\Service\TwitterService.cs:line 401
   at TweetSharp.TwitterService.WithHammock[T](String path) in C:\Users\Dimebrain\Desktop\Src\tweetsharp\src\vs2010\TweetSharp.Next\Service\TwitterService.cs:line 378
   at TweetSharp.TwitterService.WithHammock[T](String path, Object[] segments) in C:\Users\Dimebrain\Desktop\Src\tweetsharp\src\vs2010\TweetSharp.Next\Service\TwitterService.cs:line 383
   at TweetSharp_Test.Form1.GetDirectMessages() in C:\Users\kmarks2\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\TweetSharp_Test\TweetSharp_Test\Form1.cs:line 344
```

Comment: Can you show us the RAW Json that would little be more helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i can see from stack trace the [`TweetSharp.TwitterDirectMessage`](http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/6879f97aa0a0#src%2fnet40%2fTweetSharp.Next%2fModel%2fTwitterDirectMessage.cs) class schema is different from what was expected by Deserializer, may be the Json data passed has changed from last time you checked.

Also I think the Tweetsharp had some issue related to this.

As i checked in changeset on codeplex there was a change to Fix direct messages with IDs using fluent.

Check it out here.

http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/8bf46a5230bc

Try downloading new [TweetSharp v2.0.0.0 - Preview 9](http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/releases/view/59534)

Comment: Can you show us the RAW Json that would little be more helpful in determining the exact source of problem...

Comment: Awesome.  This did the trick.  Still odd that the 2 week 'broken' libs that I was using did work for a little bit.

Comment: Thanx... try to keep your library/dll updated...things change too fast around here...;-)